# Wrong proof of the functional equation for $ \zeta (s) $ but why is the result correct?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

If I introduce the function $ f(x)= |x|^{s-1} $ inside Poisson summatory formula and use the fact that

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|n|^{s-1}=2\zeta (1-s) $$

If I combine this expression in the Poisson sum formula and the Mellin transform

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{s-1}\cos(at)dt = \Gamma (s)\cos(\pi s /2)/a^{s} $$

I manage to prove Riemann's functional equation

$$ \zeta (1-s)= 2(2\pi )^{-s}\Gamma(s)\cos(\pi s/2)\zeta (s) $$

But I have proved this using BAD mathematics then why is the result correct? How is that possible ?

Comment: I'll answer your last question with a simpler example: $\frac{64}{16}=\frac{4}{1}=4$, by "simplifying by $6$". Why would a true result only derive from a good proof?

Comment: but it is supposed that CORRECT results should come form CORRECT mathematics

Comment: @JoseGarcia No. Good math implies good result, not the converse. Bad math implies anything.

Comment: Your series diverges when $s\geqslant0$, and is also undefined (at $n=0$) when $s\leqslant1.$ So it is undefined for all real $s.$

Comment: it is exists i the sense f zeta regularization :D

Comment: See [generality of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generality_of_algebra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a good proof, and in particular for an easy one, see the article of Knopp and Robins [here](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fproc%2F2001-129-07%2FS0002-9939-01-06033-6%2FS0002-9939-01-06033-6.pdf&ei=tcAnVaqCFcuPsgGYnIDABA&usg=AFQjCNF4FQZl9fywq6dgjAuaub9tE0TKjA&bvm=bv.90491159,d.ZWU). They present a new, simple proof, based upon Poisson summation.